# unable to write data in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to do a basic write operation in my firebase realtime database but i am unable to do so.

My javascript code is:

```
function submitquery()
{
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    ref.child("text").set("somevalue");
}
```

I have opened my firebase rules currently as below:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

and my current datasnapshot is as below:

[image: firebase datasnapshot]

I am able to retrieve data but the write command above is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at your function:

```
function submitquery()
{
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    ref.child("text").set("somevalue");
}
```

You are setting the firebase.database().ref() but you are not assigning any child to the ref. This will work:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('Queries');
ref.child('text').set("somvalue");
```

If you want to make your code much easier to use in the future you can also use this:

```
//Var rootRef = firebase location
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('test');

//Update test or create when test not exists
rootRef.update({
    test: "somevalue"
});
```

Hope this helps!